# Java XPath Generation Library for xml

Tags: software-testing, xml, mobile, parser

I am developing a mobile automation software which use appium internally. When i get a page source i receive an xml which contains mobile elements. My requirement is to generate a unique and shortest and relative XPath for each element(node) in the xml. 
Approches used so far:

- XSLT transformation - Not 100% Compatible with Appium.

Appreciate any help for the matter.

Answer (score 1):

XPath 3.1 has the function `path()` so `//node()/path()` will give you the paths of all nodes. However, these are XPath 3.1 paths - they will use the notation `Q{uri}local` to refer to element and attribute names. Generating path expressions with earlier versions of XPath is difficult because of the namespace problem - there's no way of generating names for namespaced elements that isn't either (a) dependent on the externally-supplied namespace context, or (b) very verbose (`*[local-name()='z' and namespace-uri() = 'y']`)